# pass variable from client-side to server-side using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to send a client-side assigned variable (in Javascript) to the server-side to use it for SQL database queries before returning it back to the client-side.

I've got the below code so far, but the `echo` always tells me **failed**.
What's wrong?

Thanx.

JS code:

```
$.ajax({   
     method: "POST",
     url: "script.php",
     data: team
});
```

PHP code:

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['team'])){
    $team = team;
    echo $team;
  }
  else {
    echo 'failed';
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whats the content of the `team` variable?

Comment: a string depending on the user's selection on the navbar (it is about soccer teams within a dashboard)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass javascript variable to php using ajax/http post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014151/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-using-ajax-http-post)

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure you're sending an object, in this case.

Example:

```
$.ajax({   
     method: "POST",
     url: "script.php",
     data: {team: team}
});
```

Your PHP code should be:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['team'])){
  $team = $_POST['team'];
  echo $team;
}
else {
  echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: still failed echo. Within the ajax part i don't want to assign the variable team since it is already assigned by user selection. So how to define the data setting in return?

Comment: getting a jquery error now, what does that mean? so picture above

Comment: @Phanti The error is saying that the browser couldn't find the `script.php` file. Check if the PHP file is on the same dir as your HTML file or change the location.

Comment: the error occurs as soon as i click a team within the navbar. Imo everything is linked properly. See screenshot above

Comment: @Phanti You don't have to include the `script.php`, this way it will not work.

Comment: Try changing the URL in JS to:  `url: "includes/script.php",`

Comment: on track again, thanks. But the initial error consists, echo says failed, meaning the variable isn't passed over to php variable -.-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199698/discussion-between-fonini-and-phanti).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to

```
include_once "script.php";
```

in order to be able to send an AJAX request to it. Instead of

```
$team = team; //incorrect
```

you need

```
$team = $_POST["team"];
```

in your AJAX request change

```
data: team
```

into

```
data: {team: team}
```